# How to parse json object with changing name using apex_json

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have an application sending me this json block

```
{
   "CHANGED VALUES":{
        "FNAME":{
            "old":"fname_old",
            "new":"fname_new"
         },
         "LNAME":{
            "old":"lname_old",
            "new":"lname_new"
         }
    }
}
```

as you can see the objects under "CHANGED VALUES" has a name that varies depending on the changed data.

how can i get to the "old" and "new" values
i tried apex_json.get_varchar2 but it needs a path to the object, its hard to code it if the object name dynamically changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the names of the objects, eg

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2   json varchar2(1000) :=
  3  '{
  4     "CHANGEDVALUES":{
  5          "FNAME":{
  6              "old":"fname_old",
  7              "new":"fname_new"
  8           },
  9           "LNAME":{
 10              "old":"lname_old",
 11              "new":"lname_new"
 12           }
 13      }
 14  }';
 15
 16    l_elem   wwv_flow_t_varchar2;
 17  begin
 18    apex_json.parse(json);
 19    l_elem := apex_json.get_members(p_path=>'CHANGEDVALUES');
 20    for i in 1 .. l_elem.count loop
 21      dbms_output.put_line('member name       : ' || l_elem(i));
 22    end loop;
 23  end;
 24  /
member name       : FNAME
member name       : LNAME

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Once you have that, then you get do standard JSON expressions to follow the path down the old/new values etc.